# Overriding serializer when using devise_token_auth and active_model_serializer

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise, active-model-serializers

I am unable to override the Rails serializer when using devise_token_auth and active_model_serializer for Devise sign_up method.

I would like to customize the returned fields from the Devise sign_up controller when querying my API.

The devise_token_auth gem documentation indicates:

*To customize json rendering, implement the following protected controller methods*

*Registration Controller*

...

*render_create_success*

...

*Note: Controller overrides must implement the expected actions of the controllers that they replace.*

That is all well and good, but how do I do this?

I've tried generating a UserController serializer like the following:

```
class UsersController < ApplicationController

  def default_serializer_options
    { serializer: UserSerializer }
  end

  # GET /users
  def index
    @users = User.all

    render json: @users
  end

end
```

but it's only being used for custom methods such as the index method above: it's not being picked up by devise methods like sign_up

I would appreciate a detailed response since I've looked everywhere but I only get a piece of the puzzle at a time.

Comment: Did you find any solution for this? It looks like the use serializer does't work on  Devise signin and signup.

Comment: Yes I did! I had to override the devise_token_auth registrations and sessions controller to add my custom attributes. I promise to post a detailed answer later today when I get home.

Comment: Hello Sumit. I posted my solution below. When using devise_token_auth user signin and signup are handled by the gem. So you need to customize the gem's controllers to add any custom functionality, including customizing the response rendered through active_model_serializer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Devise sign_up corresponds to devise_token_auth registrations controller and Devise sign_in corresponds to devise_token_auth sessions controller. Therefore when using this gem, customizing Devise sign_in and sign_up methods requires customizing both of these devise_token_auth controllers.

There are two ways to go about this based on what you need to accomplish.

**Method #1**

If you want to completely customize a method in the controller then follow the documentation for overriding devise_token_auth controller methods here: https://github.com/lynndylanhurley/devise_token_auth#custom-controller-overrides

This is what I did and it's working fine:

```
#config/routes.rb

...

mount_devise_token_auth_for 'User', at: 'auth', controllers: {
    sessions: 'overrides/sessions',
    registrations: 'overrides/registrations'
  }

...
```

This will route all devise_token_auth sessions and registrations to LOCAL versions of the controllers if a method exists in your local controller override. If the method does not exist in your local override, then it will run the method from the gem. You basically have to copy the controllers from the gem into 'app/controllers/overrides' and make any changes to any method you need to customize. Erase the methods from the local copy you are not customizing. You can also add callbacks in this way. If you want to modify the response, customize the the render at the end of the method that will return the response as json via active_model_serializer.

This is an example of my sessions controller which adds a couple of custom before_actions to add custom functionality:

```
#app/controllers/overrides/sessions_controller.rb

module Overrides

  class SessionsController < DeviseTokenAuth::SessionsController

    skip_before_action :authenticate_user_with_filter
    before_action :set_country_by_ip, :only => [:create]
    before_action :create_facebook_user, :only => [:create]

    def create
      # Check

      field = (resource_params.keys.map(&:to_sym) & resource_class.authentication_keys).first
      @resource = nil
      if field
        q_value = resource_params[field]

        if resource_class.case_insensitive_keys.include?(field)
          q_value.downcase!
        end

        #q = "#{field.to_s} = ? AND provider='email'"
        q = "#{field.to_s} = ? AND provider='#{params[:provider]}'"

        #if ActiveRecord::Base.connection.adapter_name.downcase.starts_with? 'mysql'
        #  q = "BINARY " + q
        #end

        @resource = resource_class.where(q, q_value).first
      end

      #sign in will be successful if @resource exists (matching user was found) and is a facebook login OR (email login and password matches)
      if @resource and (params[:provider] == 'facebook' || (valid_params?(field, q_value) and @resource.valid_password?(resource_params[:password]) and (!@resource.respond_to?(:active_for_authentication?) or @resource.active_for_authentication?)))
        # create client id
        @client_id = SecureRandom.urlsafe_base64(nil, false)
        @token     = SecureRandom.urlsafe_base64(nil, false)

        @resource.tokens[@client_id] = { token: BCrypt::Password.create(@token), expiry: (Time.now + DeviseTokenAuth.token_lifespan).to_i }
        @resource.save

        sign_in(:user, @resource, store: false, bypass: false)

        yield @resource if block_given?

        #render_create_success
        render json: { data: resource_data(resource_json: @resource.token_validation_response) }


      elsif @resource and not (!@resource.respond_to?(:active_for_authentication?) or @resource.active_for_authentication?)
        render_create_error_not_confirmed
      else
        render_create_error_bad_credentials
      end
    end

    def set_country_by_ip
      if !params['fb_code'].blank?

        if !params['user_ip'].blank?
          #checks if IP sent is valid, otherwise raise an error
          raise 'Invalid IP' unless (params['user_ip'] =~ Resolv::IPv4::Regex ? true : false)
          country_code = Custom::FacesLibrary.get_country_by_ip(params['user_ip'])
          country_id = Country.find_by(country_code: country_code)
          if country_id
            params.merge!(country_id: country_id.id, country_name: country_id.name, test: 'Test')
            I18n.locale = country_id.language_code
          else
            params.merge!(country_id: 1, country_name: 'International')
          end
        else
          params.merge!(country_id: 1, country_name: 'International')
        end

      end
    end

    def create_facebook_user

      if !params['fb_code'].blank?

        # TODO capture errors for invalid, expired or already used codes to return beter errors in API
        user_info, access_token = Omniauth::Facebook.authenticate(params['fb_code'])
        if user_info['email'].blank?
          Omniauth::Facebook.deauthorize(access_token)
        end
        #if Facebook user does not exist create it
        @user = User.find_by('uid = ? and provider = ?', user_info['id'], 'facebook')
        if !@user
          @graph = Koala::Facebook::API.new(access_token, ENV['FACEBOOK_APP_SECRET'])
          Koala.config.api_version = "v2.6"
          new_user_picture = @graph.get_picture_data(user_info['id'], type: :normal)
          new_user_info = {
                            uid: user_info['id'],
                            provider: 'facebook',
                            email: user_info['email'],
                            name: user_info['name'],
                            first_name: user_info['first_name'],
                            last_name: user_info['last_name'],
                            image: new_user_picture['data']['url'],
                            gender: user_info['gender'],
                            fb_auth_token: access_token,
                            friend_count: user_info['friends']['summary']['total_count'],
                            friends: user_info['friends']['data']
          }
          @user = User.new(new_user_info)
          @user.password = Devise.friendly_token.first(8)
          @user.country_id = params['country_id']
          @user.country_name = params['country_name']

          if !@user.save
            render json: @user.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity
          end
        end
        #regardless of user creation, merge facebook parameters for proper sign_in in standard action

        params.merge!(provider: 'facebook', email: @user.email)

      else
        params.merge!(provider: 'email')
      end
    end
  end

end
```

Notice the use of `params.merge!` in the callback to add custom parameters to the main controller methods. This is a nifty trick that unfortunately will be be deprecated in Rails 5.1 as params will no longer inherit from hash.

**Method #2**

If you just want to add functionality to a method in your custom controller, you can get away with subclassing a controller, inheriting from the original controller and passing a block to super as described here:

https://github.com/lynndylanhurley/devise_token_auth#passing-blocks-to-controllers

I have done this to the create method in my custom registrations controller.

Modify the routes as in method #1

```
#config/routes.rb

...

mount_devise_token_auth_for 'User', at: 'auth', controllers: {
    sessions: 'overrides/sessions',
    registrations: 'overrides/registrations'
  }

...
```

and customize the `create` method in the custom controller:

```
#app/controllers/overrides/registrations_controller.rb

module Overrides
  class RegistrationsController < DeviseTokenAuth::RegistrationsController

    skip_before_action :authenticate_user_with_filter

    #will run upon creating a new registration and will set the country_id and locale parameters
    #based on whether or not a user_ip param is sent with the request
    #will default to country_id=1 and locale='en' (International) if it's not sent.
    before_action :set_country_and_locale_by_ip, :only => [:create]

    def set_country_and_locale_by_ip
      if !params['user_ip'].blank?
        #checks if IP sent is valid, otherwise raise an error
        raise 'Invalid IP' unless (params['user_ip'] =~ Resolv::IPv4::Regex ? true : false)
        country_code = Custom::FacesLibrary.get_country_by_ip(params['user_ip'])
        #TODO check if there's an internet connection here or inside the library function
        #params.merge!(country_id: 1, country_name: 'International', locale: 'en')
        country_id = Country.find_by(country_code: country_code)
        if country_id
          params.merge!(country_id: country_id.id, locale: country_id.language_code, country_name: country_id.name)
        else
          params.merge!(country_id: 1, country_name: 'International', locale: 'en')
        end
      else
        params.merge!(country_id: 1, country_name: 'International', locale: 'en')
      end
    end

    #this will add behaviour to the registrations controller create method
    def create
      super do |resource|
        create_assets(@resource)
      end
    end

    def create_assets(user)
      begin
        Asset.create(user_id: user.id, name: "stars", qty: 50)
        Asset.create(user_id: user.id, name: "lives", qty: 5)
        Asset.create(user_id: user.id, name: "trophies", qty: 0)
      end
    end

  end
end
```

Answer (score 3):

For the specific serialiser question, here's how I did it:

### overrides/sessions_controller.rb

```
module Api
  module V1
    module Overrides
      class SessionsController < ::DeviseTokenAuth::SessionsController

        # override this method to customise how the resource is rendered. in this case an ActiveModelSerializers 0.10 serializer.
        def render_create_success
          render json: { data: ActiveModelSerializers::SerializableResource.new(@resource).as_json }
        end
      end
    end
  end
end
```

### config/routes.rb

```
namespace :api, defaults: {format: 'json'} do
  scope module: :v1, constraints: ApiConstraints.new(version: 1, default: true) do
      mount_devise_token_auth_for 'User', at: 'auth', controllers: {
          sessions: 'api/v1/overrides/sessions'
      }
      # snip the rest
```